# Bash Calculate two Arrays and add it to an Array

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to calculate two Arrays in Bash.
This should be

```
newarray=()
newarray+=$(( ${array[$counter]} / ${array[$othercounter]} ))
```

shoulnd't it?
Because when i do this, i always get this error code:

```
./testprogram.sh: line42: 24 / : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ ")
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Syntax seems right to me. Sounds like the second operand is not computing right: I would print the values of `${othercounter}` and `${array[$othercounter]}` before the operation to see what's going on.

Comment: You probably want `newarray+=( $((..)) )`; otherwise, you are just concatenating the result to the 0th element of the array, not appending an additional element *to* the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my Problem. Actually, there were two problems:

1. As @chepner allready said, there was a Syntax error when I tried to add an element to the array:

   ```
   newarray+=(*Calculation*)
   ```
2. I made this Calculation in a while loop, and when it got to the last run, I divided by an empty element.

Comment: Since you found the problem and resolved it, you should post the solution itself to help future readers who might encounter the same issue.